# Snowflake UDF Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

#Function​ snowflake database.

NOT operator in the below function in snowflake database causes UDF to return error. As per documentation NOT should be supported. What could be possible solution or work around to avoid this error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_page_category(p_url string)
RETURNS string
as
$$
SELECT min_by(page_category, config_rank) 
FROM config_page_category 
WHERE 1=1 
and regexp_like(p_url, )
AND (page_category_not_regex IS NULL 
OR NOT regexp_like(p_url, page_category_not_regex)
)
$$
```

-## Query below returns error Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

```
select udf_page_category( url ) FROM tablename e 
where url like '%zdfdsfsa%'
```

Transaction table

| ColumnA | URL |
| --- | --- |
| First | abc&welcome |
| Second | xyz$thankyou |

Config_page_category table

| page_category_regex | page_category_not_regex | output1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .*abc.* |  | output1 |
| .*xyz.* | thankyou | output2 |
| .*yyz.* | demandtor | output3 |

NOT operator in the function causes UDF to return error in snowflake database.
first column is page_category_regex
second column is page_category_not_regex

function should do the following. Input argument is url, regex resides in config_page_category lookup table

1. url should match regex in first column and if second column is null then function should return output1
2. url should match first column or should match second column then function should return output2
3. url should match first column and should not match second column then function should return output3

3rd condition above is causing an issue with NOT . What could be possible solution or work around to
avoid this error.

Comment: What error you are getting. Also give some sample data input and expected output

Comment: The classic answer is covert this to a correct join and then do the min_by and now you have your answers. While the db should be able to do this for you. Ether the optimizer cannot see how to safely do the join or it has not the pattern in its set of known translations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In your SQL you reference a column called config_rank but this is not in your table definition. Also "regexp_like(p_url, )"  appears to be a typo as it is missing the second parameter